# Ruby Instagram API content-type Wrong

Tags: json, ruby, instagram, httparty

Trying to use Instagram's API and I'm getting a `content-type` of "text/html" returned instead of "application/json".  Then, I'm having a problem coercing this into `json`.

```
require 'httparty'
rec = HTTParty.get('https://www.instagram.com/web/search/topsearch/?query=prawncocktail')
puts rec.headers    # content-type is text/html and should be 'application/json'
```

Not sure how to get this to work.  Even changing the `httparty` parameters to include "format: :json" doesn't work.  Here's some headers for a request:

```
{"content-type"=>["text/html; charset=utf-8"],
     "ig-set-password-encryption-web-key-id"=>["108"],
     "ig-set-password-encryption-web-pub-key"=>["ae57c2c94c4afb24eeda9cd759faeeb034086d0ebe60e90123baed5e38c3304f"],
     "ig-set-password-encryption-web-key-version"=>["10"],
     "vary"=>["Cookie,
     Accept-Language,
     Accept-Encoding"],
     "last-modified"=>["Sun,
     27 Dec 2020 18:13:33 GMT"],
     "expires"=>["Sat,
     01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"],
     "cache-control"=>["private,
     no-cache,
     no-store,
     must-revalidate"],
     "content-language"=>["en"],
     "date"=>["Sun,
     27 Dec 2020 18:13:33 GMT"],
     "strict-transport-security"=>["max-age=31536000"],
     "pragma"=>["no-cache"],
     "x-frame-options"=>["SAMEORIGIN"],
     "content-security-policy"=>["report-uri https://www.instagram.com/security/csp_report/; default-src 'self' https://www.instagram.com; img-src data: blob: https://*.fbcdn.net https://*.instagram.com https://*.cdninstagram.com https://*.facebook.com https://*.giphy.com; font-src data: https://*.fbcdn.net https://*.instagram.com https://*.cdninstagram.com; media-src 'self' blob: https://www.instagram.com https://*.cdninstagram.com https://*.fbcdn.net; manifest-src 'self' https://www.instagram.com; script-src 'self' https://instagram.com https://www.instagram.com https://*.www.instagram.com https://*.cdninstagram.com wss://www.instagram.com https://*.facebook.com https://*.fbcdn.net https://*.facebook.net 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' blob:; style-src 'self' https://*.www.instagram.com https://www.instagram.com 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src 'self' https://instagram.com https://www.instagram.com https://*.www.instagram.com https://graph.instagram.com https://*.graph.instagram.com https://*.cdninstagram.com https://api.instagram.com https://i.instagram.com wss://www.instagram.com wss://edge-chat.instagram.com https://*.facebook.com https://*.fbcdn.net https://*.facebook.net chrome-extension://boadgeojelhgndaghljhdicfkmllpafd blob:; worker-src 'self' blob: https://www.instagram.com; frame-src 'self' https://instagram.com https://www.instagram.com https://*.instagram.com https://staticxx.facebook.com https://www.facebook.com https://web.facebook.com https://connect.facebook.net https://m.facebook.com; object-src 'none'; upgrade-insecure-requests"],
     "x-content-type-options"=>["nosniff"],
     "x-xss-protection"=>["0"],
     "x-aed"=>["36"],
     "access-control-expose-headers"=>["X-IG-Set-WWW-Claim"],
     "set-cookie"=>["sessionid=\"\"; Domain=instagram.com; expires=Thu,
     01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT; Max-Age=0; Path=/",
     "sessionid=\"\"; Domain=.instagram.com; expires=Thu,
     01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT; Max-Age=0; Path=/",
     "sessionid=\"\"; Domain=i.instagram.com; expires=Thu,
     01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT; Max-Age=0; Path=/",
     "sessionid=\"\"; Domain=.i.instagram.com; expires=Thu,
     01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT; Max-Age=0; Path=/",
     "sessionid=\"\"; Domain=www.instagram.com; expires=Thu,
     01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT; Max-Age=0; Path=/",
     "sessionid=\"\"; Domain=.www.instagram.com; expires=Thu,
     01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT; Max-Age=0; Path=/",
     "sessionid=\"\"; expires=Thu,
     01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT; Max-Age=0; Path=/",
     "csrftoken=vjVhuWVAUCvnmYwhc6H4Z7DTgKvrKTX8; Domain=.instagram.com; expires=Sun,
     26-Dec-2021 18:13:33 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/; Secure",
     "__to_be_deleted__instagram.comMax-Age=\"\"; Domain=instagram.com; expires=Thu,
     01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT; Max-Age=0; Path=/"],
     "x-fb-trip-id"=>["1679558926"],
     "alt-svc"=>["h3-29=\":443\"; ma=3600,
    h3-27=\":443\"; ma=3600"],
     "connection"=>["close"],
     "content-length"=>["12859"]}
```

How can I get this into proper format as `json` or a `hash`?  Yes I have looked at other posts and they have no answers.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out they need OAuth authorization for simple `GET`s like this.  So this is a redo.